# What is in `tex.print` or `tex.sprint`?

Tags: luatex, lua

In an external file, I've put these 3 lines in a `.lua` file:

```
function texTest(name)
    x = tex.print("Hello " .. name)
end
```

and when I call it from `.tex` file, it gets interpreted properly. Out of curiosity, I set a breakpoint at `line 2` and called it from within the `.lua` script to inspect what is in it BUT as soon as it hits the breakpoint, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: test.lua:5: attempt to index a nil value (global 'tex')
```

I'm using VS Code with `lua` and `lua debug` extensions. Is there any way to see what is in it?

Comment: `tex.print` is part of Lua in LuaTeX but not vanilla Lua ...

Comment: @JosephWright, so there is no way to dig into this variable?

Comment: the tex module is a lua table so you can iterate over it and find it has entries such as print, but the function itself is c code and not viewable from Lua

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is `tex` the only module we can use in `luatex` or there are more?

Comment: @EmonHaque All the normal Lua tables also exists in LuaTeX, plus all the tables documented in the [LuaTeX reference](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/luatex.pdf). Beside `tex` the most important ones are `lua`, `token`, `node`, `pdf`, `kpse` and `font`, but read the documentation for an (almost) full list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Joseph Wright wrote in his comment, `tex.print` is a LuaTeX function which is not part of regular Lua, so you can not see it outside of LuaTeX.
So let's ask LuaTeX what it is: Lua comes with the `debug` library, which contains `debug.getinfo()`. This can be used to get the source of any Lua function `f` via `debug.getinfo(f).source`. Wrapping this in a (plain) LuaTeX wrapper gives:

```
\directlua{
      texio.write_nl('The source of tex.print is ' .. debug.getinfo(tex.print).source)
}
\bye
```

If we save this e.g. as `luadebug.tex` and execute it on the command line via `luatex luadebug.tex` we get:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./luadebug.tex
The source of tex.print is =[C])
warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on luadebug.log.
```

So the source is ... `=[C]`

What does that mean? It means that `tex.print` is *not* implemented through Lua, it is a C function which can be called from Lua. So to find the implementation, you have to look at the C source of LuaTeX, specifically at [ltexlib.c](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/ltexlib.c#L261).